# How can I install Spring web flow and JSF in a Spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, jsf-2, spring-webflow

I want to add in my web app Spring boot based a signup area.
To do this I want to use Spring web flow for the flows management and JSF for the gui.
How can I install Spring web flow and JSF in a single Spring boot application?

Comment: Just in case you didn't know: JSF has already since version 2.2 (released May 2013, about 6 years after the first version of Spring Web Flow) its own built-in "flows management" via the the native `@FlowScoped` annotation. So you don't necessarily need to "install Spring Web Flow" for that.

Comment: Im used Jsf flow management but  in the console appear  Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].